# Assigning fixed IP by DHCP in VMWare Workstation

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, dhcp

Windows 7 host OS, Ubuntu 12 guest OS, VMWare workstation 10.0.2.
I want my Ubuntu to use DHCP, but to get a fixed IP.

Using the Virtual Network Editor I don't see how I can do that - is there some config file that can be edited for that?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use a DHCP Reservation for the VM?

Comment: @joeqwerty - yes

Comment: Found C:\ProgramData\VMware\vmnetdhcp.conf and adde `code`dhost ubuntu {
   hardware ethernet 00:0C:29:71:66:D2;
   fixed-address 192.168.146.129;
}`/code`, client is getting a different address :(

Comment: @ranshe, you should add your solution as an answer rather than a comment, then please select it as the accepted answer to indicate it solved your problem.

Comment: I actually have a full solution, but since I'm a nOOb in terms of number of posts / rep, I will only be able to submit it tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so turns out that I forgot to restart DHCP server...

Complete solution:

1. Edit C:\ProgramData\VMware\vmnetdhcp.conf - add something like
   `host hostname
   {
   hardware ethernet 00:0C:29:71:66:D2;
   fixed-address 192.168.146.129;
   }`
2. Restart VM DHCP service
   `net stop vmnetdhcp`
   `net start vmnetdhcp`